# Не могу понять смысл введения переменной i в решении задачки

Tags: python-3.x

Сборщик ошибок. Сборщик ошибок собирает ошибки каждый день в течение пяти дней.
Напишите программу, которая ведет учет нарастающего итога ошибок, собранных в течение пяти дней. Цикл должен запрашивать количество ошибок, собираемых в течение
каждого дня, и когда цикл завершается, программа должна вывести общее количество
собранных ошибок.(вот текст задачи)

```
i = 1

total = 0
for i in range(7):
    bugs = int(input('enter the amount of bugs collected today:'))
    total += bugs

average = total / 7
print('average amount of bugs collected in a week is:', average)
```

(решение которое я нашел в интернете)

```
total_bugs = 0
for i in range (5):
    bugs = int(input("Введите количество ошибок за день "))
    total_bugs += bugs
    evarage = total_bugs/5

print(total_bugs, "Общее количество ошибок за 5 дней")
print(evarage, "Среднее арифметическое количество ошибок")
```

(мое решение)

не могу понять смысл ввода переменной i в чужом решении. Смотрел много вариантов решения и многие из них начинаются с ввода этой переменной

Comment: Нет смысла. В твоём решении тоже можно убрать, заменив на ``_``, потому что i не используется.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: И вынесите строчку `evarage = total_bugs/5` из цикла

Comment: точно подмечено, не заметил...